# Debugging an issue on an asp.net production server

Tags: asp.net, debugging, production-environment

I am attempting to debug an issue on asp.net production server. On production, when the hyperlink is clicked, it displays a pop-up window with a custom error message. There is no Try Catch Finally or any sort of error logging process currently on the server.

Given that my local version works perfectly fine, and that I am not allowed to access the production code files (being contractor), how should I go about debugging the error ?

Comment: "Sorry for the inconvenience but the feature has generated an error. This error has been recorded, please use the back button and try again."   :-)

Comment: So that sentence must be in your code base some where...that is where I would start.

Comment: All I have to do is think about the code I've seen others write. In cases like these it's usually some ridiculous try/catch that just catches all unexpected errors. Finding the error message in the code would be useless.

Comment: if they won't let you remotely debug as @b1naryj says, you should try to replicate the environment as closely as possible on your machine. Are they running the site under a different trust level? Are they running the app pool as a specific user account? Can you set your environment with the same settings and try to replicate the error?